# Windows 8 /WP7 . IsolatedStorageSettings vs XML

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have a lot of data (all elemenents of the periodic table) in a xml file.

Should I load every time the app starts or use the make a list of element objects in the IsolatedStorageSettings?

Is the second allowed? Which one would be more efficient?

Comment: where is the xml file? in a remote location? Because you can store the xml file in isolated storage.

Comment: It's in the isolated storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would serialize the file manually and store it, then deserialize it on launch - I am assuming that the periodic table you have is used with more than one element at a time.

It would make no sense at all to save that data in a key/value store like `IsolatedStorageSettings`.

`ISS` is generally recommended for application settings or for data that changes over time as the application is used. Your scenario is not exactly like this.